# MS Access shortest duration of a stage of a race

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I need to get the line of data of the shortest duration of each stage of a race. To do that I have been looking for answers for the past hours but I need to use MS Access and I don't have any access to the ROW_NUMBER() function.

So I have done that code which obviously doesn't work

num_etape is the ID of the stage
num_dossard is the ID of the racer
Resultat is the duration of the racer to complete the stage

```
select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY H.Num_etape ORDER BY Num_etape, Num_dossard, Resultat desc) as N 
from (
    select distinct Num_dossard, Num_etape, Resultat FROM import_donnees) as H) as X
where N = 1
order by  X.Num_etape, X.Num_dossard, X.Resultat desc, N desc
```

Is there a method to do that?

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as a text table.

Comment: Or this https://database.guide/5-ways-to-select-rows-with-the-minimum-value-for-their-group-in-sql/#:~:text=A%20quick%20and%20easy%20option%20is%20to%20construct,31%20%7C%20%7C%20Spike%20%7C%2015%20%7C%20%2B--------------%2B------------%2B